# How to find non-consecutive characters in a string?

Tags: optimization

I have a dictionary text and I am trying to find the longest word containing specified characters in this dictionary text. The letters will be input by the user. for example, if the user input "red", the program will have to find the longest word that contains "r", "e", and "d". I was able to find the words that contain either "r", "e", or "d".
How do I shrink the premises so that the words that are stored contains all the letters that are input by the user, regardless of their order of the input?

Comment: What is the format of the contents of the `"dictionary.txt"` file? The `for word in data_file:` is reading the file a **line** at time, not by the word—does that matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the built-in [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set) type to simplify and speed-up what you want to do because they make it trivial to quickly test whether all the letters are in each word of the file. I also recommend that you use [`with`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) statements to automatically make sure your files are closed.

If the format of the `"dictionary.txt"` file is one word per line, it might be possible to speed this up. However, since which you have never described what it is, the following doesn't assume that and should work whether there is one or several on each line of the file.

```
dict_filename = "dictionary.txt"
outp_filename = "find_right_words.txt"

# user's input
letters = input("Please enter the letters to include: ")
letters = set(letters)  # convert string to set of characters

print("searching for letters: {}".format(', '.join(sorted(letters))))

# find all words in dictionary file that contain all the letters and store them in a file
with open(dict_filename, "r") as data_file, \
     open(outp_filename, "w") as find_right_words:
    for line in data_file:
        for word in line.split():
            if letters.issubset(word):  # all letters in word?
                find_right_words.write(word+'\n')

print("file {!r} created".format(outp_filename))
```

However, if all you want to do is find the longest word with all the letters, you don't really need to create the `"find_right_words.txt"` file because that can be determined at the same time as the words in the file are being checked.

Here is what I mean:

```
# find longest word in dictionary file that contains all the letters
with open(dict_filename, "r") as data_file:
    longest_word_len = 0
    for line in data_file:
        for word in line.split():
            if(len(word) > longest_word_len  # is word longer than longest word...
               and letters.issubset(word)):  # and all letters in it?
                longest_word, longest_word_len = word, len(word)

print("longest word found: {!r}".format(longest_word))
```

Note that if there are multiple words of the same length containing all the letters, this will ignore all but the first.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
letter = input("Please enter the letters to include: ")

data_file = open("dictionary.txt").read().splitlines()

words = [i for i in data_file if all(b in i for b in letter)]

print(max(words, key = len))
```

This algorithm loops through the word list and creates a new list containing all the words that have every letter from the user input in them. Then, the code finds the longest word from the filtered list.